# Storing woocommerce_page_title in a variable and display it in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, page-title

I would like to display the page-title over the category-image. I copied this code

```
<h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
```

from the "template-archive-product.php" to "woocommerce-hook.php" as followed:

```
$html .= '<h1 class="page-title">'<?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?>'</h1>';
```

Now the title doesn't appear. When I am checking the dev tools, the title is like a html-comment.

```
<h1 class="page-title"><!--?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?--></h1>
```

It would be great if someone could help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template [function `woocommerce_page_title()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_page_title.html#656-690) is echoed by default as you can see in [its source code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_page_title.html#656-690)… But there is an optional argument to be used **to return the data**, instead of echoing it. For that you need to turn this argument from (default) `true` to `false`.

This is useful when **you need to set this data in a variable**, just as you are trying to do. So the functional code should be a bit different:

```
$html .= '<h1 class="page-title">' . woocommerce_page_title( false ); . '</h1>';
```

Tested and works.

Or alternatively you can use php buffering functions, to get the same thing, this way:

```
ob_start();
?>
<h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
<?php
$html .= ob_get_clean();
```

Nothing will be outputted and the data will be appended in the `$html` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$html .= '<h1 class="page-title">' . woocommerce_page_title() .'</h1>';
```

Instead of:

```
$html .= '<h1 class="page-title">'<?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?>'</h1>';
```

Comment: but isn't the lack of echo means that this title would print right out ignoring the = mark?